# Mathematica won't give any answer to a PDE system

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, boundary-condition-at-infinity

I've been trying to double check Transformer Design book's solution to a PDE. Mathematica, however, gives me no answer. In other words, it just writes the DSolve expression back. Here is the equation:

[image]

The book solves it using separation of variables method.

Input:

```
equ = 1/r*D[r*D[h[r, z], r], r] - h[r, z]/r\.b2 + D[h[r, z], {z, 2}] == I*\[Sigma]*\[Mu]*\[Omega]
DSolve[{equ, h[a, z] == i/(2 Pi*a), h[r, c/2] == i/(2 Pi*r), h[r, c/2] == -i/(2 Pi*r), h[\[Infinity], z] == 0}, h[r, z], {r, z}]
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: What are `i` and `j`?  If `Sqrt[-1]`, they should be `I`.  Also, `h[r, z]` seems to be missing from the right side of `equ`.

Comment: All that said, `DSolve` indeed is failing to solve a PDE that you or I can solve.  Sometimes, that happens.

Comment: `i` is the electrical current, and `I` is the imaginary unit. Book uses j to express the imaginary unit (electrical engineering convention). The right side where? Can't seem to find the point. Thanks, btw, @bbgodfrey.